# Generate a feed from followed users items with GraphQL (nestjs)

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql, nestjs, feed

I'm new to graphql, I have some users that can follow each other and they have a list of products, what would be the way to go to create a feed of products of the users you follow?

The `user` has a property called `listing` that has a relation to the `products` (which has a relation to the user with a property called `author`)

Basically the user looks like this:

```
User object
{
  ...
  listing: [ "id1", "id2" ]
}
```

and the product like this:

```
Product object
{
  ...
  author: { User1 }
}
```

what would be the best approach to write a query to get the products from the followed users?

other maybe useful information:

- the data is stored in a mongodb database
- the `listings` and the `author` are stored as ids but can be populated with the full object

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using the following mongoose find:

```
this.productModel
      .find({
        seller: { $in: following },
      })
```

where `following` is the array of id's the user is following, then I populate the `seller` with `.populate('seller').exec()`